# Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед словом "например"?

Tags: запятые

Не смотреть телевизор(,) например.

Answer (score 2):

***Не смотреть телевизор, например.***

Если вы привели предложение целиком, то да, "например" выделяется запятыми по общему правилу: вводные слова обособляются.

Если же вводное слово стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, запятыми оно не выделяется — выделяется только сам оборот. Так, в следующем предложении запятой перед "например" нет.

***Нужно с чего-то начинать, не смотреть телевизор например.***